# Django - save multiple input parameters to database

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm using the below custom form in my `Django` app:

**`forms.py`**

```
class UpdateURLForm(forms.ModelForm):

    VideoURL = forms.URLField()
    MainDescription = forms.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        model = Listing
        fields = ('VideoURL', 'MainDescription',)
```

Then, in **`views.py`** I import the form and then I render the fields into my `HTML` template:

```
def edit_info(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateURLForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            VideoURL = form.cleaned_data['VideoURL']
            MainDescription = form.cleaned_data['MainDescription']
        else:
            form = UpdateURLForm()
    return render(request, 'myapp/updateinfo.html', {'form': form})
```

**`HTML`**:

```
<form action="#" method='post' class="card shadow-soft border p-4 mb-4">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="video">Video URL:</label>
        {{form.VideoURL|add_class:"form-control shadow-soft"}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="video">Video URL:</label>
        {{form.MainDescription|add_class:"form-control shadow-soft"}}
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-dark mt-2 animate-up-2 text-right"
                type="submit">Update</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Now, my question is: how can I render the field `MainDescription` in the template in order to save both information into the database? The way I rendered the second field (`MainDescription`) doesn't work. Thanks!

**Edit**

So, I have two fields in my custom form which (VideoURL and MainDescription) which I would like to use to update some info in the DB. When I try to render in the `HTML` template both are getting the same ID whereas I was expecting that each field of the form to be rendered:

```
<input type="text" name="VideoURL" value="https://videourl.com" maxlength="100" class="form-control shadow-soft" required="" id="id_VideoURL">
```

I do not figure out what I am missing.

Comment: Please define "does not work". Also note that 1/ the `else` clause in your view is not at the right place - if that's your real code, you should have a `NameError` when doing a GET on this url, 2/ your view code doesn't save anything  and 3/ it looks like it wants to be the "update" part of a crud, but you're not passing any model instance to your form so it will only create new records.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers - I edited my questions. You have mentioned that I am doing something wrong regarding CRUD operations. Could you please post an example of how am I supposed to do or point me to some documentation/other example? Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Every ModelForm has a [save()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) method. This method creates and saves a database object from the data bound to the form. A subclass of ModelForm can accept an existing model instance as the keyword argument instance; if this is supplied, save() will update that instance. If it’s not supplied, save() will create a new instance of the specified model:

**EXAMPLE 1 with forms.ModelForm**

**`forms.py`**

```
class UpdateURLForm(forms.ModelForm):    
    class Meta:
        model = Listing
        fields = ['video_url', 'main_description']
```

So you can ease [save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) your form.

**`views.py`**

```
def edit_info(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateURLForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save()
    else:
        form = UpdateURLForm()
    return render(request, 'myapp/updateinfo.html', {'form': form})
```

**EXAMPLE 2 with forms.Form**

**`forms.py`**

```
class UpdateURLForm(forms.Form):
    video_url = forms.URLField(label="Video Url")
    main_description = forms.CharField(label="Description", max_length=100)
```

You can also import your model and [create an object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects).

**`views.py`**

```
from models import Listing

def edit_info(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateURLForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            listing = Listing(video_url=form.cleaned_data.get('video_url'), main_description=form.cleaned_data.get('main_description'))
listing.save()
    else:
        form = UpdateURLForm()
    return render(request, 'myapp/updateinfo.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: I am able to save the updated video URL without using the `save()` method. So, how is it different?

Comment: @anonymoussss You can also import your model `Listing`. See example in my answer.

Comment: It wil be better to use `forms.Form`. I've updated my answer.